# Is is allowed to create new variables in the constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I was wondering if it is allowed/good practice to create temporary variables in a constructor? I only need the variable for a return value of a function
Something like:

```
class A
{
  private: 
    int var;
  public:
    A(); 
};

A:A()
{
   var = 0;
   int tmp_var = somefunction();
   ...
   Some Code
   ...
}
```

Comment: Possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690579/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-declared-in-a-class-constructor

Comment: Yes, this is no problem. The temporary variable will go out of scope by the end of the constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not good practice or bad practice. It's just one of those things you do when you need to store a value somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can even create static one. Constructor is just a function to call at start.